# How to override pagination in custom Joomla component?

Tags: joomla, pagination, joomla2.5

I created a custom component listing persons.

Now, my component stops at 20 persons per page, due to pagination.
**How can I override pagination and just show all persons, be it 5, 100 or 999?**

This is what I've tried:

1. setting `$this->pagination->viewAll = true` in `view.html.php` => no difference.
2. setting `$this->setState('list.start', 0)` and `('list.limit', 1000)` in `function populateState` in the model-file => no difference

What can I do?

Comment: So do you have pagination elements (e.g. select menu, page numbers) showing in your list view?

Comment: I can insert them in my template, of course. But I don't want to have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I did it. I changed the following function in `.../site/models/persons.php`.
The `parent`-function would overwrite `list-limit`, so I had to `setState...` **after** calling `parent::populateState()`.

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    (...)

    parent::populateState($ordering, $direction);
    $this->setState('list.limit', 0); // <---- this did the trick
}
```